# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host - MPI

Tags: c, mpi

I doing an application using C and MPI that makes a vector by Matrix multiplication, but I keep having errors like Error posting readv , and An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (10054)
Here is the code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "mpi.h"

#define W 5
#define H 5

void make_matrix(int[]);
void make_vector(int []);

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  int myrank,size,k;
  int matrix[H*W];
  int vec[W];
  int res[W];
  static int col_count = 0;

  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myrank);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);

  MPI_Bcast(vec,W,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  if(myrank != 0)
  {
    for(k=0; k<W; k++)
    {
      vec[k]+= matrix[k*W+col_count];
    }
    col_count++;
    printf("%d ",vec[col_count]);
  }

  MPI_Finalize();
}

void make_matrix(int a[])
{
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<H*W; i+=1)
  {
    a[i] = i;
  }
};

void make_vector(int v[])
{
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<H; i++)
    v[i] = i*2;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MPI_Bcast()` is a *collective* function, which means that every process in the communicator must call it. In other words, don't call `MPI_Recv()`. So get rid of your `if(myrank == 0)` conditional and have all processes call:

```
MPI_Bcast(vec,W,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Note that I have `vec` above, not `&vec`; since `vec` is already an array, it is the pointer that MPI needs. Also, your result will appear in `vec` on the non-root processes; there is no need for the separate `arr` array.

I recommend that you read some examples of MPI and try to make your code look more like them.

Comment: Thank you for answering , I did what u told me and I had no errors, However, the answer is not correct. I removed the myrank conditional for the MPI_Bcast , but I used it when calculating the values ... is that correct ? I will edit the code above ....

Comment: @mahmoud I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. My answer solves your communication errors. There may be plenty of other issues in your code, but I don't know what your goals are; that's a totally different question.

Comment: Just 1 more question, about communication , Is it right to process whatever calculation um doing with all processing units except the root , or should I involve the root also ?

Comment: @mahmoud The root should be involved too. That's the very nature of parallel computing; all nodes are involved in whatever you're trying to accomplish.